# How can I make sure flex also aligns inner-divs on 1 row?

Tags: css, flexbox

I noticed that flex can align input-tags, regular text and probably other stuff perfectly on 1 line with `flex-direction:row;`. But this seems to break when one of things is a div. Example:

```
<html><body style="display:flex;">
<div style="flex-direction:row;">
  <input type="text" value="a"/>
  <input type="text" value="b"/>
  <div>c</div>
  <input type="text" value="d"/>
  <input type="text" value="e"/>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Everything starts fine, but once the c-div starts, it jumps down, and does it again at the end of the c-div. (From there one it works fine again).

How can i make sure all 5 are one line using flex ?

The reason i use flex is that it looks easier then messing around regular css.
(They mention in the flex-docs *"flexbox aims at providing a more efficient way to lay out, align and distribute space among items in a container"* so it seems like this is how i should do it...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your scenario, display: flex should be applied to the immediate div inside the body tag, Not to the body tag.

Try this,

```
<body>
  <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row;">
    <input type="text" value="a"/>
    <input type="text" value="b"/>
    <div>c</div>
    <input type="text" value="d"/>
    <input type="text" value="e"/>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This seems to work, thanks ! But I have no idea why...It would seem logical to assume that "display:flex" would be inherited from the body tag, so i have no idea why this isn't the case